# How to define an Apache Camel Route "from SOAP Web Service"?

Tags: rest, soap, cxf, apache-camel, apache-axis

I am working on a small **camel** application that needs to read data from a third party SOAP Web Service.

I wanted a camel route similar to this:

```
public class MyCamelRouter extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("???:mySoapOrRestWebService")
        .to("jms:queue:someQueue"));
}
```

At first i thought that this could be done with [camel-cxf](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html), but its documentation does not mention it.

The only solution that i've found so far is to implement a [polling consumer](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html) and use it with a timer on the "from" of my route definition.

Is this solution the correct one? Or can this be achieved with some other camel component?

I also need to define a similar route but using a REST web service in the "from"

Comment: A bit of clarification. There is already a service and you need to get the data from that service . Am i right?

Comment: Yes Naveen Raj, you are right. I need to recive the information from an existing service.

Comment: How will this route be called/initiated? In other words what client is going to use this route? When you add the web service component(CXF) in the from part of the route you are creating a web service producer not consumer so if you start off with the following route `from(cxf)` you are creating a new web service that has a camel route as the back end. YOu cannot go `from(some existing service)`. If you can tell me how the service will be called i can give you some more information on how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks lmenaolivares. Namphibian has shown the right direction but I would like to give my own version as it will help you as a first time user of camel. If you need to get some information from an existing service then you are probably writing a client for the service. In such case you need write a producer , say a     <to uri = "calling existing service "> endpoint.  So please let us know on what basis, like a scheduled run or once in a day , the existing service is to  be called. Thus we can help you

Comment: Thanks to both of you. What i need is to call a existing web service every 20 or 30 seconds. Now i know that i cannot call it on the "from", but what i can do is from(someTimer).to(existingWsUsingCxf).to(myProcessor). Am i correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that i found for this is to use a timer in the from and call the SOAP web service afterwards.

The code i used looks like this:

```
public class MyCamelRouter extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("timer:soapRequestTimer?{options}")
        .to("cxf:serviceUrl"));
        .to("jms:queue:someQueue"));
}
```